# Video in the VSE differs from actual rendered result

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am currently trying to use the Blender Video Sequence Editor for editing a video with picture-in-picture sequences. I came up with the problem that the video displayed in the VSE looks totally different than the rendered resulting video: both videos in the picture-in-picture sequences are not synchronous anymore, one of them gets rendered way faster than the other, although in die VSE they are synchronous. Both videos have 29fps, which is what I used as render framerate as well.

Could anyone please help me with this issue? I am really confused that what I see in the VSE obviously is not what the rendered result is going to look like.

Unfortunately, I am unable to attach my project as it is confidential corporate training material.

Thank you very much in advance!
Larissa

Comment: could you upload a screenshot from your vse and renderproperties?

Comment: What do you mean by "picture-in-picture" exactly?

Comment: Have you made sure, that while playing back the preview in the VSE you have "AV Sync" and "Frame Dropping" enabled in the Playback menu of the timeline? Your videos FPS should also match to the Frame Rate setting under Dimensions in the Render Properties.

Comment: Did you accidently change the Strobe setting in one of the Strips' Filter Properties?