# Unable to identify frame for cut in VSE - Bug?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

in addition to my [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35695/video-in-the-vse-differs-from-actual-rendered-result), I have another problem with the Video Sequence Editor in Blender.

I am editing a screen capture, where I need to identify that one frame in which a window disappears. I found the correct frame and cut the clip. Afterwards, I searched for that frame again. When I approach the frame in which the window disappears from the left, frame number 1044 is the very first frame, in which the window is gone. I would expect that if I go one single frame left, the window would appear again. But in fact, it doesn't. I have to go left until I reach frame 1040, which is then the very first frame, in which the window appears again.

So in summary, I am unable to find the right frame for separating the screen capture as it makes a difference whether I am approaching it from the left or right.

Do you consider this a bug? And if not: Could anyone tell me how to get rid of this "feature"?

I am using Blender v2.75 on a Win7 system.

---

I tried to follow 3pointedit's instructions and it seems to reveal a problem with the screen capture clip.  I started a complete new Blender-project and added the screen capture as a movie. Then, I did "Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Indices" with the settings attached. Unfortunately, Blender crashes immediately without any error message, it just exits.

I tried the same with one of the GoPro clips and it works perfectly (same settings).

So obviously, there is something wrong with the screen capture clip...

[image: Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Indices Settings]

Comment: This make me think that your imput video, though it appear to be 29fps (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35695/video-in-the-vse-differs-from-actual-rendered-result), maybe is not. I had similar problem and I solved by re-encoding the imput video to "trusted 29fps" with an external application.

Comment: Do you have the same issue also with other imput files?

Comment: That's due to decoding problems with the internally used ffmpeg library. Here's a workaround to receive the best possible accurate frames out of your footage: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate a timecode file for the clip (it lives in the proxy panel of strip properties), when creating the TC you can choose to NOT render a proxy. The playback of media should be much better. But transcoding to a more simple codec is best (less compression, more real frames).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are dealing with an MPEG, AVCHD or similar compressed video file that is not using an **Intra-Frame** compression scheme, but is using **Inter-frame**. Inter-Frame is not great for editing because it does not contain the information for each frame but has certain keyframes and *delta frames* that only record he changes from the prevous keyframe.
(read this: http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/45144/interframe-coding).

Sometimes (I know this from motion tracking footage) the direction in which the stream is read will make a difference and will yield errors.

To correct this you'd need to **transcode**  your source to an image sequence, or a codec that is using intra-frame (unique frames)