# Wrong tracking marker position

Tags: tracking, masking, timeline

I have encountered a serious problem when using tracking markers:
I tracked a single point over a range of 3000 frames in small steps e.g. I manually corrected the position every 50 frames. When rewatching the 50 frames, all the tracking seems to be very accurate. However, when I rewatch the whole footage, suddenly in some ranges the accuracy is terrible. But somehow these ranges vary and are at different positions from time to time. Even more surprising is that even those frames at the beginning of the 50 frames, which HAVE to be correct, aren't. To me it seems like there is either some offset in the displaying of the markers, or they get saved wrongly somehow. Has anyone an idea, what could be the reason for this?

EDIT: Just changing the input format from .mp4 to .png solved the problem completely.

Comment: There are many variables on this question. You do not describe what it is you are tracking and how, blurry or distorted it might be on the original video. It is possible indeed that instead of "manually correcting" the tracking, you are "offsetting" the tracker, please edit your post and add some more information and images. Also please inform us what kind of codec the video is in. Codecs that use Long GOP  encoding will not track correctly when played backwards, or when jumping from one keyframe to the next. In those cases it is better to generate an image sequence to track from.

Comment: Read also: [Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful)

Comment: and [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)

Comment: Read also: [Movie clip editor playback problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51732/movie-clip-editor-playback-problem/51733#51733) and [camera track - was good, but breaks after editing an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35220/camera-track-was-good-but-breaks-after-editing-an-object/35229#35229)